# How to do C# @ before string in python

Tags: python

I have something like this:

```
"([a-z0-9./]+)\."
```

but I can't compile this because there is some special characters like `\` and `+`.
I know in C# you can put `@` before the string how I do it in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by "compile"? Python is an interpreted language. Is there more code than what you're showing us here? (something involving `re.compile`, maybe...?)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is `verbatim string`

Answer (score 1):

using string as raw string is how to do a c# @'string'
Running this sample code shall get you going.

```
print '\\'
print r'\\'
```

see section 2.4.1 from the link below for further documentation 
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html

Answer (score 0):

Either put a 'r' before the string.
`r'**...\...**'`
This makes it a raw string.
Or escape the backslash by putting another backslash in front of it.
Like this:
`'**...\\...**`
if you do the later you are able to use backslash for other things in the same string. Like `\n` or `\t`

Answer (score 0):

For what your trying to do, I suggest using two back-slashes, like this:

```
"mooga\\blooga"
```

The first backslash escapes the second one.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow and am still getting used to the interface